# Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-hooks, javascript-import

I'm a beginner in Reactjs, I was working on this small project with show me a random user using an externe Api but the problem I'm facing is it keeps showing me this warning every time when I try to render the User Component in the App.js file.

Warning: 
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
(for built-in components) or a class/function
(for composite components) but got: null.

what am I doing wrong, please? thanks.

```
// App.js 

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import User from "./components/User";

const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/'

function App(){
const [User, setUser] = useState(null)
const [getRandomUser, setgetRandomUser] = useState(false)

  const fetchData = async()=>{
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const {results} = await response.json();
    const {name: { first : firstName, last: lastName },
    street : {number, name},
    login : { password},
    dob :{age},
    picture : {thumbnail: image},
          email,
        phone } = results[0]
    setUser(  {
      fullName : `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
      Adresse: `${number} ${name}`,
      email: email,
      age: age,
      password: password,
      phone: phone,
      img: image
    } )
   
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[getRandomUser] )

  return (
  <User/>

  )
  
}

export default App
```

```
// User.js

import React from 'react'

function User (){
 return <div>User</div>
}

export default User
```

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a naming collision. You have both

```
import User from "./components/User";
```

and

```
const [User, setUser] = useState(null)
```

This is one reason why precise variable names and following the standard conventions are useful - something that isn't a component nor a class probably shouldn't have a variable that starts with a capital letter. Consider calling the state `userData` instead, and then you can pass it down to the child as a prop for the child to parse as desired, for example

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)
```

```
return (
  <User userData={userData} />
)
```

````
function User ({ userData }){
 return <div>User {userData ? userData.fullName : ''}</div>
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables with the same name

```
import User from "./components/User";
```

and

```
const [User, setUser] = useState(null)
```

Just rename the state

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
```